# Cual seria la url del siguiente update en mysql

Tags: mysql

```
String url = "http://dominio.es/crear_dato?dato="+dato;
```

Esta url sería para la siguiente linea de php:

```
 $insert="INSERT INTO dato (dato) VALUES ('{$dato}')";
```

¿Cual sería la url para la siguiente linea de php?

```
$insert="UPDATE tabla SET dato = '$valor_nuevo' WHERE dato='$valor'";
```

Que tendría que poner en el navegador para probar el php, me pierdo con el WHERE.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: algo así no?: [String url = "http://dominio.es/crear_dato?valor_nuevo="+valor_nuevo+"&valor="+valor;](http://dominio.es/crear_dato?valor_nuevo="+valor_nuevo+"&valor="+valor;), no se cual sea el archivo que mandaras llamar porque ya no sería crear_dato.

Comment: Vaya, eso lo he intentado y me da error así que debe ser otra cosa la que tengo mal.